# Check if the spacebar is being pressed and the mouse is moving at the same time with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way to check if the space bar and at the same time track what direction the mouse is moving and how far etc.

Point of this is that I want to replicate how Photoshop scrolls when you hold the space bar, left mouse button and you move the mouse, but without having to hold down the left mouse button.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use [`keydown()`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) and [`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) to track if the space bar is pressed or not and look at that state in your [`mousemove()`](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) event handler. For example:

```
var space = false;
$(function() {
  $(document).keyup(function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
      space = false;
    }
  }).keydown(function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
      space = true;
      console.log('space')
    }
  });
});
```

And then your `mousemove()` handler can see if it's pressed or not.

Answer (score 4):

you will probably have to be watching for the keydown event, check to see that it's the spacebar, set a variable saying it's down, unset it when the keyup event is seen.

so, then you would look for mouse movements when that variable was set indicating the spacebar was pressed.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution:

```
var allowed = true;
$(document).ready(
function () {
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'space', function () {
        if (!allowed) return;
        allowed = false;
        $('#viewport').
            dragscrollable();
    });
    $(document).bind('keyup', 'space', function () {
        allowed = true;
        $('#base').off('mousedown');
        return false;
    });

});
```

Works with jQuery and the Dragscrollable Plugin.