# Autoscroll to bottom of page then top and repeat

Tags: jquery, autoscroll

I have created a dashboard which echos out all the rows but I want an auto scroll which will slowly scroll down the bottom of the page and then scroll slowly back to the top and repeat. I have googled this and can't get a working code. I have been looking for jQuery codes but anything will do.

Because the page will adjust all the time it cant have fixed height scroll.

Not sure if you need more information but if you do I will update this question.

Regards
Gambit

Comment: Show us the code you have already tried.

Comment: Well tried just auto scroll to bottom of page but that didnt work. function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,1);
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',10);
}

Comment: See my answer below, using the callback of the animate function allows you to have two methods calling back and forth to each other so it repeatedly scrolls up and down.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use something like this.

```
//run instantly and then goes after (setTimeout interval)

    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 4000); 
    },4000);
  var scrolltopbottom =  setInterval(function(){
         // 4000 - it will take 4 secound in total from the top of the page to the bottom
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 4000); 
    },4000);

    },8000);

​//Use this to stop the scroller -> clearInterval(scrolltopbottom);
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/NaP8D/11/

Comment: That works but how do I reduce the speed when it scrolls down?

Comment: @TheGambit If i understand you correctly you need to make use of easing in the animate method. You need to change it from linear to something else. Include jquery ui for some alternatives: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html

Comment: Edit look at my update post.

just increase or decrease "4000" value to whatever speed and interval you want.

Comment: Thats great thanks. Can you just comment on what each of the 4000 number represents?

Comment: Updated my post again with explination. Enjoy! :)

Comment: Thanks Tim. Just reading your final line in the code. Is it possible to use a key such as spacebar to toggle the scrolling on and off?

Comment: Yes its possible.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249203/check-if-the-spacebar-is-being-pressed-and-the-mouse-is-moving-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 2):

you should try this for better result

```js
//run instantly and then goes after (setTimeout interval)

$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 4000);

setTimeout(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 4000); 
},4000);


setInterval(function(){
     // 4000 - it will take 4 secound in total from the top of the page to the bottom
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 4000);
setTimeout(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 4000); 
},4000);
    
},8000);


$('html, body').mouseover(function(e) {
$(this).stop(true);
      
    }).mouseout(function() {
         $(this).stop(false);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:2000px; float:left; width:100%;">
Text text
Text text
    Text text
    
    Text text
    Text text
    Text text
    Text text
    
    
    
    Text text
    Text textv
    Text text
    Text text
    
    Text text
    Text textText text
     Text textText text Text textText text
      Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p>Text textText text
     <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p>
        <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p> <p>
             Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text Text textText text
       </p>
    

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/neelu/gvvnd0tt/8/

Answer (score 1):

Here, this should work good, just change 5000 to the time in ms to adjust the speed.

http://jsfiddle.net/BDc6S/3/

```
function scrollDown(el) {
    el.animate({
        scrollTop: el[0].scrollHeight
    }, 5000, function() {
        scrollUp(el)
    });
};

function scrollUp(el) {
    el.animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 5000, function() {
        scrollDown(el);
    });
};

scrollDown($("html,body"));​
```

Comment: The pause between stop and start scrolling seems to increase for every loop.